# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and it's my first time ever using an API.
so I was trying to fetch the MetaWeather API that's how I did it

```js
fetch('https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Asynchronous JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Asynchronous JavaScript</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I get those two errors and I really don't understand why.

asynchronous.html:101 GET https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
(anonymous) @ asynchronous.html:101
asynchronous.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: CrossOrigin.me's SSL certificate is not valid. Maybe try a different proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/

These seem to be two URLs. 
https://crossorigin.me/
https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/

Which URL are you trying to hit ?

Comment: @ShaharyarKirmani OP is trying to use a CORS proxy, that's why you see two URLs

Comment: @Phil Alright i was not aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: you'd be better off using your own server as a proxy for the requests rather than rely on third-party CORS breaking (and perhaps terms of service breaking for the site you are trying to reach) sites that may disappear tomorrow

Comment: the API documentation contains the following: `Drop me an email if you're going to make more than maybe a request a minute to this` - you're going to (ab)use that API by using a CORS buster, they'll probably block you

Comment: Thank you guys that has been more than helpful. Although It's important to note here that I'm not using my own server as this's all an experiment on my localhost so there's really no actual server, and definitely not trying to abuse the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the url succeeding this proxy: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ instead of https://crossorigin.me/

It worked for me.